# On startup of uvicorn execute script and cache the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I am using the `fastapi` to build a RESTful webservice. To run the service, I am using `uvicorn`. On startup of `uvicorn`, I want to execute the my python script, which will make a database call and cache some data, so that it can be reused until `uvicorn` is running. I tried looking up documents of [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/), but did not find any reference.

Is there anyway to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Use the FastAPI `startup` event. From [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/?h=startup#startup-event):

> ```
> from fastapi import FastAPI
>
> app = FastAPI()
>
> items = {}
>
>
> @app.on_event("startup")
> async def startup_event():
>     items["foo"] = {"name": "Fighters"}
>     items["bar"] = {"name": "Tenders"}
> ```
>
> In this case, the startup event handler function will initialize the
> `items` "database" (just a dict) with some values.
>
> You can add more than one event handler function.
>
> And your application **won't start receiving requests until all the
> startup event handlers have completed.**

(this feature is actually implemented in [starlette](https://www.starlette.io/events#registering-events) - the ASGI framework that FastAPI is built on)